# PHP Mailer - foreach in message body

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer

I want to included results using foreach inside the body of an email message.  PHP Mailer seems to just cut off the message when I add the foreach statement. Any ideas on how to include multiple results in the message body?

```
$mail->Body    = '*** Automated email - do not reply ***<br><br>Hello '.$Name.', <br><br>We were able to connect you with the following services. <br><br> ';
foreach($findResult['data'] as $key=>$findData){ 
 if($findData['CompanyEmail'][0] != NULL || $findData['CompanyPhone'][0] != NULL) { 
     echo $findData['CompanyName'][0]; 
     echo $findData['CompanyContact'][0]; 
     echo $findData['CompanyPhone'][0];
     echo $findData['ContactEmail'][0];
     }?><br><?php }
$body .='<br><br>Thank you for using our directory.<br><br><br>Regards,<br><br>Sender';
```

P.S. If i take out the ';' before the foreach, I get an error.

Comment: You have `$mail->Body` and `$body`, which are totally unrelated...and in the `foreach` you just output stuff. If you want everything to be in the mail body, put it there and not all over the place.

Comment: @TillHelge isn't that why people come here? To learn?

Comment: @Styphon This page is not well suited to teach the essentials. From the question it is easy to see that even the most basic debugging techniques (echo/log the variable) are unknown to the OP and he will never learn them from SO, because all he gets here are working code snippets, while he really would need a proper explanation of what's the problem and how to go about detecting the problem himself.

Comment: @TillHelge I agree with Styphon. When complete beginners post questions such as the OP which include their code, what they are expecting, shows some effort, and isn't requesting an application to be written for them; that's what SO is for. It's the questions such as 'How to send mail in PHP? Can someone write a script which mails user input for me' which aren't welcome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using echo you need to use `$mail->Body .=` to continue the string. Like this:

```
$mail->Body    = '*** Automated email - do not reply ***<br><br>Hello '.$Name.', <br><br>We were able to connect you with the following services. <br><br> ';
foreach($findResult['data'] as $key=>$findData){ 
    if($findData['CompanyEmail'][0] != NULL || $findData['CompanyPhone'][0] != NULL) { 
        $mail->Body .= $findData['CompanyName'][0]; 
        $mail->Body .= $findData['CompanyContact'][0]; 
        $mail->Body .= $findData['CompanyPhone'][0];
        $mail->Body .= $findData['ContactEmail'][0];
    }
}
$body .='<br><br>Thank you for using our directory.<br><br><br>Regards,<br><br>Sender';
```

If, as I suspect, `$body` should also be part of the e-mail, then change that to `$mail->Body .=` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Styphon. I really appreciate it. It works, and I can see why it didn't earlier.  :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this.